# OpenCV KCF Tracking a Pre-Selected Object

Tags: python, opencv

looking for some guidance on how to implement KCF tracking and whether it is suitable for the project I am creating. Working on latest version of OpenCV on Python to create a program that tracks specific objects as they move around in front of the camera. the ultimate goal being just to count how many of that specific object when its in the bottom half of the frame. Currently have a working version building my own cascade but had a terrible time trying to implement my own tracking.

I've since discovered the tracking built in and have been messing around with some example code from the Opencv and Learnopencv sites, focusing on KCF. This code is below.

```
import cv2
import sys

(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

img = cv2.imread('OXO200Front.jpg')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

# Set up tracker.
# Instead of MIL, you can also use

tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN']
tracker_type = tracker_types[2]

if int(minor_ver) < 3:
    tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
else:
    if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
    if tracker_type == 'MIL':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
    if tracker_type == 'KCF':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    if tracker_type == 'TLD':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
    if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
    if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ok, frame = cap.read()

#Initializing a bounding box 
bbox = img

bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

while(1):
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);
if ok:
    p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
    p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
    cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
else :
    # Tracking failure
    cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), 
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
    cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), 
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);

# Display FPS on frame
cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), 
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

# Display result
cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

K = cv2.waitKey(1)
if (K==27):
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is this the correct way to go about this? How do I go about using images of the objects I want to track? rather than a bounding box selection at the start. Any advice or help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KCF is a decent and fast single object tracker. It might have trouble tracking an object when there are multiple objects of a similar type in the frame. If you’re tracking a chicken, for example, and it goes into a flock of other chickens of the same breed, there’s a high chance the tracker will drift on to another chicken.

You have two tasks here: object detection and object tracking. But maybe what you actually require is just object class and location. For that, I’d recommend looking up YOLO object detection and localiser. It might do the job directly.

All that said, if you still want to use KCF, first you need to decide on the object you want to track. If your cascade can recognise the object, you could simply take small (multi-scale) image patches in the first frame, note their co-ordinates and pass them to your cascade to see if they contain the object or not. If they contain the object, use the image patch coordinates to initialise KCF (rather than drawing them manually) and let it track. It will drift at some point, so use your cascade detector to redetect and reinitialise at some defined interval.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you possibly direct me to a link/guide or some documentation as to how I go about implementing the multi-scale section you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: You just want to implement a sliding window over the images (frame) returns an ROI (or Mat in C++ opencv) that you can use to feed your cascade. Different sizes of ROI, (resized to fit into your cascade) is the multi-scale I meant. I assume your cascade classifier wants specific image dimensions?